# Changing Domain name on Fedora 20

Tags: dns, fedora, portal, intranet

The existing domain name of our intranet is a Static IP address. Is it possible to change this address into Domain name without using a DNS Server!! we are current setting up a intranet for our thesis so the company requested to change its address to name so that it can be remember by the employee. I already searched and tried different methods but still those result requires DNS server!! It is really possible to change the name without DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

I know of a few routes to do this, all with some potentially serious drawbacks:

1. NetBIOS names, better for predominantly Windows shops.
2. Bonjour, better for Macintosh shops.

If you are a mixed shop, it's still possible to do this by installing Bonjour on the Windows boxes and/or enabling Windows sharing on the OSX boxes.

There's also:

3. Hosts files.

This is the least handy of the choices as it entails distributing modified files to each client that you expect to access the named server.

All those options generally entail a good bit of headache and problem for even a small office.  Registering a name with an external DNS provider (assuming you are using DNS at all) is usually a far easier route, and doesn't necessarily mean you have to run your own DNS server.

Comment: Sir have you experience changing the name of a portal in fedora 20? if you do what linux program did you used?

Comment: If by "portal" you mean the host itself, then yes -- using `hostname`.  I don't think that's really what you want, though.